# How can I generate a link to a controller action in Rails 3.2.7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, action

Here's the HTML I'd like to generate:

```
<li><a href="/Home/Index">HOME</a></li>
```

Meaning, a link to the Index action of the Home controller.

How can I achieve this in Rails without generating the entire `<a>` element?

Does something like this exist?

```
<li><a href="<%= link_tag(:controller => "home", :action => "index") %>">HOME</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_to` generates all the markup, so you don't need to write it inside an `<a>` tag.

```
<%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => :home, :action => :index}, :class => "awesome", :id => "super-awesome" %>
```

spits out

```
<a href="/home/index" class="awesome" id="super-awesome">Home</a>
```

Edit: Also, this is your friend - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `link_to` helper? If your route is named `home` than:

`link_to('Home', home_path)`

will generate

`<a href="/Home/Index">HOME</a>`

You can retrieve your route names by running `rake routes` from the command line.

Comment: That's fine I guess, but what if I need custom classes or id's set to that element?

Comment: @Serg use `link_to 'Home', home_path, class: 'yourclass', id: 'yourid'` in that case